# How to use symfony's use_dynamic_javascript() helper?

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1

There are no examples of use anywhere, or even an explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the source, make with it what you will. (Doesn't appear overly useful IMO).

```
566 /**
567  * Adds a dynamic javascript to the response object.
568  *
569  * The first argument is an internal URI.
570  * The helper automatically adds the sf_format to the internal URI, so you don't have to.
571  *
572  * @see sfResponse->addJavascript()
573  */
574 function use_dynamic_javascript($js, $position = '', $options = array())
575 {
576   $options['raw_name'] = true;
577 
578   return use_javascript(_dynamic_path($js, 'js'), $position, $options);
579 }
```

Comment: Thanks Ian! I was just curious if it was enough to significantly help with the process of building dynamic JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I know the question has its age, but I consider the problem is still there for many of us :)

After banging my head against the wall several hours, I want to share some info with you :P

How to use use_dynamic_javascript() helper in symfony [here](http://goodies.lemonsoftware.eu/doku.php?id=sym:dynamicjs).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this helper adds non-static (generated by you) JS to response. First parameter is an url as if it was passed `url_for()`.